# Find out if companies are using Careers in your area

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, employers

Would it be possible to add a search option which will tell you if employers are looking at the careers site in your area?  I wouldn't expect to see the name of which employers are looking, but I think it would help, when you are looking for a job, if anyone in your area is actually even paying to see resumes.

Where I live, I'm not certain how many people have even heard of Stack Overflow, let alone have realized the potential about finding programmers on it.  I don't live in a small town, I just don't think the market penetration for it has really happened here (don't know why, you may insert jokes about the quality of programmers at this point in time).  When I start looking for a new place of "opportunity", it'd be nice to know if I don't get any response, because no one has figured to look at SO, or just because I'm lame (not arguing the latter could definitely be possible).

Comment: Shouldn't we just hope that they get employers some day?

Comment: I put hope and praying for the winning lottery numbers in the same category.  I don't count on either of them to help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now have **public employer search statistics** for CV holders, under the stats tab -- just click "show detail>>" to expand.

This list is queried dynamically about every hour, and reflects current live data.

[image]

Comment: Looks great, Jeff.  Thanks go out to the team on this one.

Comment: As usual, you are the man, Jeff.

Answer (score 5):

It would actually be nice if Careers was a two way street.  Both parties are paying for the service, but all the candidates can do is "bait" their CV in the hopes it attracts attention.  They are a very passive partner in the job matching service.

It'd be much better if both parties were actively involved in finding matching situations.

Comment: I agree - a good job engine should be like a dating agency where both parties should be able to discover the love for each other with the minimum of fuss and get to second base without any fumbling or endless expensive dinner dates.

Comment: @Kev - bitter, much?  ;-D